# How to swipe out cards using ionic framework

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, swipe

when I'm dragging the card to left or right & releasing it, it is coming back to its original position. I want like When i swipe them to right or left they should swipe away from screen. [Code tried](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/unable-to-swipe-away-card-in-ionic/128756/2)

Comment: Need more information. Maybe post a Plunker? https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you can detect the onSwipe event, try using jQuery's .hide() function to hide the element, and then you can remove it from your data structure.